# column count doesn't match value count at row 1 mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query in which the query tries to record for each season the average obtained by the rest of the players in that same season and when making the query it sends me this error I am working on mysql and this is my query and my boards

```
CREATE TABLE jugadores (
  codigo int NOT NULL,
  Nombre varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  Procedencia varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  Altura varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  Peso int DEFAULT NULL,
  Posicion varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  Nombre_equipo varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo),
  FOREIGN KEY (Nombre_equipo) References equipos(Nombre)
)engine=innodb;

CREATE TABLE equipos (
  Nombre varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  Ciudad varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  Conferencia varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  Division varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Nombre)
)engine=innodb;


CREATE TABLE jugador (
  codigo int NOT NULL,
  Nombre varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  Procedencia varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  Altura varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  Peso int DEFAULT NULL,
  Posicion varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
)engine=innodb;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temporada (
  idTemporada INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  FechaInicio DATETIME NOT NULL,
  FechaFin DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idTemporada))
ENGINE = InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Temporada_Equipo_Jugador (
  Id INT(11) NOT NULL,
   Nombre_equipo varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  jugador_codigo INT(11) NOT NULL,
  Temporada_idTemporada INT(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Nombre_equipo) References equipos(Nombre),
 foreign key (jugador_codigo) references jugador(codigo),
 foreign key (Temporada_idTemporada) references Temporada(idTemporada));

insert into temporada values (( 
    select AVG(a.estadisticas) 
    from estadisticas a, jugador b 
    where a.nombre = b.codigo 
    group by b.id_jugador
));
```

this is the error `column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps you should mention that is happens when you run the insert at the end. I noticed that you have not described estadisticas which is used by your insert. Any reason for this?

Comment: I noticed that the columns in the tables do not match the columns in your insert. Do you mean to insert? Or do you mean to update with "average obtained by the rest of the players"? Can you explain in more details? If you mean to insert you'll need to identify the column you want to data inserted into if you only fetch one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see a few issues for you to fix in your database code.

First: to your question.  When you `INSERT` a row into a table, you must provide a way for MySQL to assign a value, or a `NULL` value, to every column in the row. Your `Temporada` table contains four columns, and they are all declared `NOT NULL` without any default value. That means MySQL cannot accept your `INSERT` instructions unless you give values for all columns.

Your `idTemporada` column should be declared like this so MySQL gives each row a unique value:

```
idTemporada INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Then you should use an insert statement something like this, where you provide one number and two date/time values.

```
   insert into temporada 
          (Nombre,        FechaInicio, FechaFin)
   select AVG(something), start_date,  end_date
     from something
```

I fear I don't understand your data well enough to tell you where to get those date/time values.

Second: Your `Nombre` receives a number, an `AVG()`. Therefore it should be declared as a number, a `DOUBLE`, not `VARCHAR(30)`.

```
 Nombre DOUBLE NOT NULL,
```

Third, your other tables also need `AUTO_INCREMENT` on their `id` values.

Please consider my remarks, then work on your code, and ask another question if you still need help.